# I wrote a kivy program but it does not open the window

Tags: python, android, kivy

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

kivy.require('1.11.1')

class MyKivyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="Hello World")

MyKivyApp().run()
```

the above is what i wrote but it is not opening the window

Comment: Show us exactly how you run this code.

Comment: it runs perfectly well here.

Answer (score 0):

i copy and past the code into `vscode` on `windows11` with `kivy` installed.

i press "f5" to run the code.

the app launches and looks like this:

[image]

so it appears to be good code...